# Unreadable Int16 from UInt8List, wrong data when cast asByteArray

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried to get int, short from data, the data get from websocket, but some thing is wrong, and when i cast from UInt8List -> Byte Data -> UInt8List, it add 2 new uint8 in my array. Any one suggest me how is correct way to get int from byte array. (It's big Endian, my code in Swift and the base write data in Dart still correct). Thank anyone for reading this.

I am using 'dart:typed_data'; and get data from WebSocket (dart:io)

```
print(responseData); // UInt8List: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]
var byteData = responseData.buffer.asByteData();
var array = byteData.buffer.asUint8List(); 
print(array); // UInt8List: [130, 7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]
var shortValue = responseData.buffer.asByteData().getInt16(0);
print(shortValue); // -32249 ( 2 first byte: [0 ,1] so it must be 1 )
```

Answer (score 4):

There's something else going on, because your code does not add any extra bytes - and actually, it doesn't use `array`.

This code:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  Uint8List responseData = Uint8List.fromList([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]);
  print(responseData); // UInt8List: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]
  var byteData = responseData.buffer.asByteData();
  //var array = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  //print(array); // UInt8List: [130, 7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]
  var shortValue = responseData.buffer.asByteData().getInt16(0);
  print(shortValue); // -32249 ( 2 first byte: [0 ,1] so it must be 1 )
}
```

prints (as expected)

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]
1
```

EDIT - as suggested in the comment, the Uint8List you have is in fact a view on a ByteBuffer with a non-zero offset. So, `responseData.buffer` is that underlying buffer, which includes additional bytes. The simplest solution is to make a copy of the view.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  Uint8List original = Uint8List.fromList([130, 7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]);
  print(original);

  Uint8List view = Uint8List.view(original.buffer, 2);
  print(view);
  print(view.buffer.lengthInBytes); // prints 9
  print(view.buffer.asByteData().getUint16(0)); // unexpected result

  Uint8List copy = Uint8List.fromList(view);
  print(copy.buffer.lengthInBytes); // prints 7
  print(copy.buffer.asByteData().getUint16(0)); // expected result
}
```

Comment: When i tried to cast to another type it throw exception so i think its UInt8List: 
Unhandled exception:
type '_Uint8ArrayView' is not a subtype of type
Yes, i really cant understand why responseData can be change, 
    print(responseData); // [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]
    var shortValue = responseData.asByteData().getInt16(0);
    print(shortValue); // -32249

    Uint8List responseTest = Uint8List.fromList([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]);
    print(responseTest); // [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 49]
    var shortTest = responseTest.buffer.asByteData().getInt16(0);
    print(shortTest); //of course its 1

Comment: I suspect that you are getting a view that doesn't have an offset of zero e.g. from `Uint8List.view()`. Your simplest fix will be to make a clean `Uint8List` before doing anything else. `Uint8List copy = Uint8List.fromList(responseData);` then use `copy.buffer.asByteData()`.